# How to deserialize JSON data from Jira?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, jira-rest-api

In Visual Studio I am able to make a connection to Jira witch returns the string (shortened to one instance for the example)

```
"expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "15237",
        "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/15237",
        "key": "THU-219",
        "fields": {
            "customfield_10110": null,
            "fixVersions": [],
            "customfield_10111": null,
            "customfield_10112": null,
            "resolution": null,
            "customfield_10113": [
                "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@a34aea2[id=53,rapidViewId=9,state=CLOSED,name=THU Sprint 7,goal=Survive!,startDate=2018-03-07T22:33:01.297Z,endDate=2018-03-21T22:33:00.000Z,completeDate=2018-03-20T19:16:10.159Z,sequence=53]",
                "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@28b8057[id=58,rapidViewId=9,state=ACTIVE,name=THU Sprint 8,goal=make sure fixes fix ticket,startDate=2018-03-20T19:16:10.291Z,endDate=2018-04-03T19:16:00.000Z,completeDate=<null>,sequence=58]",
                "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@3e1efb35[id=43,rapidViewId=9,state=CLOSED,name=THU Sprint 5,goal=,startDate=2018-02-06T20:44:37.751Z,endDate=2018-02-20T20:44:00.000Z,completeDate=2018-02-20T20:15:10.688Z,sequence=43]",
                "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@2ce8e5a0[id=48,rapidViewId=9,state=CLOSED,name=THU Sprint 6,goal=,startDate=2018-02-20T20:15:01.461Z,endDate=2018-03-06T20:15:00.000Z,completeDate=2018-03-07T22:32:22.792Z,sequence=48]"
            ],
            "customfield_10114": "1|hzz39z:",
            "customfield_10500": null,
            "customfield_10104": null,
            "customfield_10105": null,
            "customfield_10501": null,
            "customfield_10106": null,
            "customfield_10502": null,
            "customfield_10503": null,
            "customfield_10107": null,
            "customfield_10108": null,
            "customfield_10109": null,
            "lastViewed": null,
            "epic": {
                "id": 15229,
                "key": "THU-211",
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/epic/15229",
                "name": "project Name",
                "summary": "Epic encompassing all TBD-related issues",
                "color": {
                    "key": "color_2"
                },
                "done": false
            },
            "priority": {
                "self": "https://nebook.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/1",
                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/highest.svg",
                "name": "Highest",
                "id": "1"
            },
            "customfield_10100": "2018-01-23T17:12:27.999-0600",
            "customfield_10101": null,
            "customfield_10102": null,
            "labels": [
                "user's first name"
            ],
            "customfield_10103": null,
            "customfield_10731": null,
            "customfield_10610": null,
            "customfield_10611": null,
            "customfield_10733": null,
            "customfield_10612": null,
            "customfield_10613": null,
            "timeestimate": null,
            "customfield_10614": null,
            "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": null,
            "customfield_10735": null,
            "customfield_10615": null,
            "versions": [],
            "customfield_10616": null,
            "customfield_10617": null,
            "issuelinks": [
                {
                    "id": "14337",
                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issueLink/14337",
                    "type": {
                        "id": "10000",
                        "name": "Blocks",
                        "inward": "is blocked by",
                        "outward": "blocks",
                        "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10000"
                    },
                    "inwardIssue": {
                        "id": "18233",
                        "key": "THU-289",
                        "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/18233",
                        "fields": {
                            "summary": "summary",
                            "status": {
                                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10804",
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                                "name": "Code Review",
                                "id": "10804",
                                "statusCategory": {
                                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
                                    "id": 4,
                                    "key": "indeterminate",
                                    "colorName": "yellow",
                                    "name": "In Progress"
                                }
                            },
                            "priority": {
                                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/1",
                                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/highest.svg",
                                "name": "Highest",
                                "id": "1"
                            },
                            "issuetype": {
                                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10300",
                                "id": "10300",
                                "description": "Created by Jira Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a user story.",
                                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/issuetypes/story.svg",
                                "name": "Story",
                                "subtask": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "14336",
                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issueLink/14336",
                    "type": {
                        "id": "10001",
                        "name": "Cloners",
                        "inward": "is cloned by",
                        "outward": "clones",
                        "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10001"
                    },
                    "inwardIssue": {
                        "id": "18233",
                        "key": "THU-289",
                        "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/18233",
                        "fields": {
                            "summary": "summary",
                            "status": {
                                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10804",
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                                "name": "Code Review",
                                "id": "10804",
                                "statusCategory": {
                                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
                                    "id": 4,
                                    "key": "indeterminate",
                                    "colorName": "yellow",
                                    "name": "In Progress"
                                }
                            },
                            "priority": {
                                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/1",
                                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/highest.svg",
                                "name": "Highest",
                                "id": "1"
                            },
                            "issuetype": {
                                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10300",
                                "id": "10300",
                                "description": "Created by Jira Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a user story.",
                                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/issuetypes/story.svg",
                                "name": "Story",
                                "subtask": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "assignee": null,
            "status": {
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10804",
                "description": "",
                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                "name": "Code Review",
                "id": "10804",
                "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
                    "id": 4,
                    "key": "indeterminate",
                    "colorName": "yellow",
                    "name": "In Progress"
                }
            },
            "components": [],
            "customfield_10730": null,
            "customfield_10600": null,
            "customfield_10601": null,
            "customfield_10602": null,
            "aggregatetimeestimate": null,
            "customfield_10603": null,
            "customfield_10604": null,
            "customfield_10605": null,
            "customfield_10727": null,
            "customfield_10606": null,
            "customfield_10728": null,
            "customfield_10607": null,
            "customfield_10608": null,
            "customfield_10729": null,
            "customfield_10609": null,
            "creator": {
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=name",
                "name": "name",
                "key": "key",
                "accountId": "accountId",
                "emailAddress": "email",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                    "24x24": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                    "16x16": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                    "32x32": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                },
                "displayName": "name",
                "active": true,
                "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
            },
            "subtasks": [],
            "reporter": {
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=name",
                "name": "name",
                "key": "key",
                "accountId": "557058:ecce9327-53cc-4787-bcd5-ecf16309600b",
                "emailAddress": "email",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                    "24x24": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                    "16x16": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                    "32x32": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F40f53dffbd45ed6f545a40ec91d4843f%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                },
                "displayName": "name",
                "active": true,
                "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
            },
            "aggregateprogress": {
                "progress": 0,
                "total": 0
            },
            "customfield_10711": null,
            "customfield_10712": null,
            "closedSprints": [
                {
                    "id": 53,
                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/53",
                    "state": "closed",
                    "name": "THU Sprint 7",
                    "startDate": "2018-03-07T22:33:01.297Z",
                    "endDate": "2018-03-21T22:33:00.000Z",
                    "completeDate": "2018-03-20T19:16:10.159Z",
                    "originBoardId": 9,
                    "goal": "Survive!"
                },
                {
                    "id": 43,
                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/43",
                    "state": "closed",
                    "name": "THU Sprint 5",
                    "startDate": "2018-02-06T20:44:37.751Z",
                    "endDate": "2018-02-20T20:44:00.000Z",
                    "completeDate": "2018-02-20T20:15:10.688Z",
                    "originBoardId": 9,
                    "goal": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 48,
                    "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/48",
                    "state": "closed",
                    "name": "THU Sprint 6",
                    "startDate": "2018-02-20T20:15:01.461Z",
                    "endDate": "2018-03-06T20:15:00.000Z",
                    "completeDate": "2018-03-07T22:32:22.792Z",
                    "originBoardId": 9,
                    "goal": ""
                }
            ],
            "progress": {
                "progress": 0,
                "total": 0
            },
            "votes": {
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/THU-219/votes",
                "votes": 0,
                "hasVoted": false
            },
            "worklog": {
                "startAt": 0,
                "maxResults": 20,
                "total": 0,
                "worklogs": []
            },
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10300",
                "id": "10300",
                "description": "Created by Jira Agile - do not edit or delete. Issue type for a user story.",
                "iconUrl": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/images/icons/issuetypes/story.svg",
                "name": "Story",
                "subtask": false
            },
            "timespent": null,
            "sprint": {
                "id": 58,
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/58",
                "state": "active",
                "name": "THU Sprint 8",
                "startDate": "2018-03-20T19:16:10.291Z",
                "endDate": "2018-04-03T19:16:00.000Z",
                "originBoardId": 9,
                "goal": "make sure fixes fix ticket"
            },
            "project": {
                "self": "https://nebook.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/11510",
                "id": "11510",
                "key": "THU",
                "name": "name",
                "projectTypeKey": "software",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "https://nebook.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10324",
                    "24x24": "https://nebook.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10324",
                    "16x16": "https://nebook.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10324",
                    "32x32": "https://nebook.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10324"
                }
            },
            "aggregatetimespent": null,
            "resolutiondate": null,
            "workratio": -1,
            "watches": {
                "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/THU-219/watchers",
                "watchCount": 2,
                "isWatching": false
            },
            "created": "2017-12-14T18:01:28.505-0600",
            "customfield_10300": null,
            "customfield_10301": null,
            "updated": "2018-03-20T14:16:13.195-0500",
            "timeoriginalestimate": null,
            "description": "description",
            "timetracking": {},
            "customfield_10401": [],
            "customfield_10402": null,
            "customfield_10006": "THU-211",
            "customfield_10403": null,
            "security": null,
            "customfield_10007": null,
            "attachment": [],
            "flagged": false,
            "summary": "summary",
            "customfield_10000": "{}",
            "customfield_10001": null,
            "customfield_10002": null,
            "customfield_10400": null,
            "environment": null,
            "duedate": null,
            "comment": {
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/15237/comment/23890",
                        "id": "23890",
                        "author": {
                            "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=name",
                            "name": "name",
                            "key": "key",
                            "accountId": "accountId",
                            "emailAddress": "email",
                            "avatarUrls": {
                                "48x48": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                                "24x24": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                                "16x16": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                                "32x32": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                            },
                            "displayName": "name",
                            "active": true,
                            "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                        },
                        "body": "text describing the issue",
                        "updateAuthor": {
                            "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=name",
                            "name": "name",
                            "key": "key",
                            "accountId": "557058:d4a31d0e-7944-488b-9f89-fcfec87b95ac",
                            "emailAddress": "email",
                            "avatarUrls": {
                                "48x48": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D48%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                                "24x24": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D24%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                                "16x16": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=16&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D16%26noRedirect%3Dtrue",
                                "32x32": "https://avatar-cdn.atlassian.com/b232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fb232453b514d10d65f986fe7f2df592c%3Fd%3Dmm%26s%3D32%26noRedirect%3Dtrue"
                            },
                            "displayName": "name",
                            "active": true,
                            "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                        },
                        "created": "2018-01-23T17:12:27.999-0600",
                        "updated": "2018-01-23T17:12:27.999-0600"
                    }
                ],
                "maxResults": 1,
                "total": 1,
                "startAt": 0
            }
        }
    },
```

I have been able to find some examples on here that deal with this issue however I have not been able to find anything that deals with repeated key words like my JSON data has.

The only real information I care about is the initial "Key" value (In this example "THU-219") and the status "name" field which is under "fields" -> "issuelinks" -> "inwardIssue" -> "fields" -> "status" -> "name"

I would like to be able to print out in the form of
 Key: THU-219 \n
 Status: "Code Review"

To achieve this I have attempted this code (after I have made a secure connection)Where respStr is the entire string which contains the snippet above in the same format for each issue. Am I creating my classes wrong? Because I am unable to get the expected data. I am aware that there is an option in Visual studio to "paste as JSON classes" but I getting an error that won't allow me to utilize this feature so I need a way to accomplish this without relying on that paste special feature.

```
 String respStr = response.Content;

        JiraObject jira = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JiraObject>(respStr);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Key>kvp in jira.Issues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key:" + kvp.Value.Keys);
            Console.WriteLine("Status:" + kvp.Value.Status)
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

class JiraObject
{
    [JsonProperty("issues")]
    public Dictionary<string, issues> Issues { get; set; }

}

class issues
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public Dictionary<string, Key> Keys { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Dictionary<string, Fields> fields { get; set; }

}

class Key
{
    public Key Keys { get; set; }
}

class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("issuelinks")]
    public Dictionary<string, issuelinks> issueLinks { get; set; }
}

class issuelinks
{
    [JsonProperty("inwardIssue")]
    public Dictionary<string,inwardIssue> inwardIssues { get; set; }
}

class inwardIssue
{
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Dictionary<string, inwardFields> inwardFields { get; set; }
}

class inwardFields
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public Dictionary<string, status> status { get; set; }
}

class status
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public Dictionary<string,name> name { get; set; }
}

class name
{
    public name names { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON snippet isn't valid. As for how to deserialize your content from JIRA, a quick way to help you out could be to use http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Kevin Avignon your JSON is not valid. It's missing a "{" at the beginning and you need to remove the "," at the end so that we can use it (but this were just a minor problem).

In order to get the classes you need you can just dump your JSON into [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/). In your case i got the following:

```
public class Color
{
    public string key { get; set; }
}

public class Epic
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public bool done { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string inward { get; set; }
    public string outward { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
}

public class StatusCategory
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string colorName { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public StatusCategory statusCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Priority2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Issuetype
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool subtask { get; set; }
}

public class Fields2
{
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Priority2 priority { get; set; }
    public Issuetype issuetype { get; set; }
}

public class InwardIssue
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public Fields2 fields { get; set; }
}

public class Issuelink
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public InwardIssue inwardIssue { get; set; }
}

public class StatusCategory2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string colorName { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Status2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public StatusCategory2 statusCategory { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Creator
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls2
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Reporter
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls2 avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class Aggregateprogress
{
    public int progress { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class ClosedSprint
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime completeDate { get; set; }
    public int originBoardId { get; set; }
    public string goal { get; set; }
}

public class Progress
{
    public int progress { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Votes
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int votes { get; set; }
    public bool hasVoted { get; set; }
}

public class Worklog
{
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<object> worklogs { get; set; }
}

public class Issuetype2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool subtask { get; set; }
}

public class Sprint
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public int originBoardId { get; set; }
    public string goal { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls3
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string projectTypeKey { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls3 avatarUrls { get; set; }
}

public class Watches
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int watchCount { get; set; }
    public bool isWatching { get; set; }
}

public class Timetracking
{
}

public class AvatarUrls4
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls4 avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls5
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateAuthor
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls5 avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class Comment2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public UpdateAuthor updateAuthor { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public List<Comment2> comments { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int startAt { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public object customfield_10110 { get; set; }
    public List<object> fixVersions { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10111 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10112 { get; set; }
    public object resolution { get; set; }
    public List<string> customfield_10113 { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10114 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10500 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10104 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10105 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10501 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10106 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10502 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10503 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10107 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10108 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10109 { get; set; }
    public object lastViewed { get; set; }
    public Epic epic { get; set; }
    public Priority priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime customfield_10100 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10101 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10102 { get; set; }
    public List<string> labels { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10103 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10731 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10610 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10611 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10733 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10612 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10613 { get; set; }
    public object timeestimate { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10614 { get; set; }
    public object aggregatetimeoriginalestimate { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10735 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10615 { get; set; }
    public List<object> versions { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10616 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10617 { get; set; }
    public List<Issuelink> issuelinks { get; set; }
    public object assignee { get; set; }
    public Status2 status { get; set; }
    public List<object> components { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10730 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10600 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10601 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10602 { get; set; }
    public object aggregatetimeestimate { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10603 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10604 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10605 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10727 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10606 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10728 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10607 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10608 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10729 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10609 { get; set; }
    public Creator creator { get; set; }
    public List<object> subtasks { get; set; }
    public Reporter reporter { get; set; }
    public Aggregateprogress aggregateprogress { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10711 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10712 { get; set; }
    public List<ClosedSprint> closedSprints { get; set; }
    public Progress progress { get; set; }
    public Votes votes { get; set; }
    public Worklog worklog { get; set; }
    public Issuetype2 issuetype { get; set; }
    public object timespent { get; set; }
    public Sprint sprint { get; set; }
    public Project project { get; set; }
    public object aggregatetimespent { get; set; }
    public object resolutiondate { get; set; }
    public int workratio { get; set; }
    public Watches watches { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10300 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10301 { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    public object timeoriginalestimate { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Timetracking timetracking { get; set; }
    public List<object> customfield_10401 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10402 { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10006 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10403 { get; set; }
    public object security { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10007 { get; set; }
    public List<object> attachment { get; set; }
    public bool flagged { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10000 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10001 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10002 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10400 { get; set; }
    public object environment { get; set; }
    public object duedate { get; set; }
    public Comment comment { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}
```

Now you only need to remove everything that you don't need (and maybe rename class names if you want). After doing so you will have your classes that you can work with.

The following classes will just store the initial "key" value and the "name" of the status as you asked for in your post.

```
public class Status
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Fields2
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class InwardIssue
{
    public Fields2 Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Issuelink
{
    public InwardIssue InwardIssue { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public List<Issuelink> Issuelinks { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize your json you can now use the following code:

```
string content = //your json
RootObject ro = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

If something is still wrong then pls write so and i will try to figure something out.

Comment: Thank you to you and Kevin for the resource of json2csharp. It has been a big help. As far as once the classes are created.. I am trying your string content = //your json
RootObject ro = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);                however I get the error message An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.                 I'm extremely new to deserializing JSON

Comment: Can you post your current code and the beginning of your json?

Comment: I went ahead and answered as an Answer that way the code will appear nice.

Comment: The beginning of the JSON is  {
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 65,
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "15245",
            "self": "https://companyName.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/15245",
            "key": "THU-227",
            "fields": { all the stuff in fields and above}

Comment: This JSON is not valid. There is a semicolon after the quotation marks of the value from "issue". After removing it i were able to parse the json. I also posted a comment right under your answer with the code because there is also something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fabian,

Below are the generated classes from the website you provided after I put my entire JSON string into the website.

```
 public class I18nErrorMessage
{
    public string i18nKey { get; set; }
    public List<object> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Customfield10502
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public I18nErrorMessage i18nErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class I18nErrorMessage2
{
    public string i18nKey { get; set; }
    public List<object> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Customfield10503
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public I18nErrorMessage2 i18nErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public string key { get; set; }
}

public class Epic
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public bool done { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class I18nErrorMessage3
{
    public string i18nKey { get; set; }
    public List<object> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Customfield10616
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public I18nErrorMessage3 i18nErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Assignee
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class StatusCategory
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string colorName { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public StatusCategory statusCategory { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls2
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Creator
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls2 avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls3
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Reporter
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls3 avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class Aggregateprogress
{
    public int progress { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Customfield10711
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls4
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Customfield10712
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls4 avatarUrls { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
}

public class ClosedSprint
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime completeDate { get; set; }
    public int originBoardId { get; set; }
    public string goal { get; set; }
}

public class Progress
{
    public int progress { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Votes
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int votes { get; set; }
    public bool hasVoted { get; set; }
}

public class Worklog
{
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<object> worklogs { get; set; }
}

public class Issuetype
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool subtask { get; set; }
    public int avatarId { get; set; }
}

public class Sprint
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public int originBoardId { get; set; }
    public string goal { get; set; }
}

public class AvatarUrls5
{
    public string __invalid_name__48x48 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__24x24 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__16x16 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__32x32 { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string projectTypeKey { get; set; }
    public AvatarUrls5 avatarUrls { get; set; }
}

public class Watches
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int watchCount { get; set; }
    public bool isWatching { get; set; }
}

public class Timetracking
{
}

public class I18nErrorMessage4
{
    public string i18nKey { get; set; }
    public List<object> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Customfield10400
{
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public I18nErrorMessage4 i18nErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public List<object> comments { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int startAt { get; set; }
}

public class StatusCategory2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string colorName { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Status2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public StatusCategory2 statusCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Priority2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Issuetype2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iconUrl { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool subtask { get; set; }
    public int avatarId { get; set; }
}

public class Fields2
{
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public Status2 status { get; set; }
    public Priority2 priority { get; set; }
    public Issuetype2 issuetype { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public Fields2 fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public List<object> fixVersions { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10110 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10111 { get; set; }
    public object resolution { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10112 { get; set; }
    public List<string> customfield_10113 { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10114 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10104 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10500 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10501 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10105 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10106 { get; set; }
    public Customfield10502 customfield_10502 { get; set; }
    public Customfield10503 customfield_10503 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10107 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10108 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10109 { get; set; }
    public object lastViewed { get; set; }
    public Epic epic { get; set; }
    public Priority priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime? customfield_10100 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10101 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10102 { get; set; }
    public List<object> labels { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10103 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10731 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10610 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10611 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10612 { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10733 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10613 { get; set; }
    public object timeestimate { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10614 { get; set; }
    public object aggregatetimeoriginalestimate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? customfield_10735 { get; set; }
    public List<object> versions { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10615 { get; set; }
    public Customfield10616 customfield_10616 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10617 { get; set; }
    public List<object> issuelinks { get; set; }
    public Assignee assignee { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public List<object> components { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10730 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10600 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10601 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10602 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10603 { get; set; }
    public object aggregatetimeestimate { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10604 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10605 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10606 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10727 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10728 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10607 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10608 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10729 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10609 { get; set; }
    public Creator creator { get; set; }
    public List<object> subtasks { get; set; }
    public Reporter reporter { get; set; }
    public Aggregateprogress aggregateprogress { get; set; }
    public Customfield10711 customfield_10711 { get; set; }
    public Customfield10712 customfield_10712 { get; set; }
    public List<ClosedSprint> closedSprints { get; set; }
    public Progress progress { get; set; }
    public Votes votes { get; set; }
    public Worklog worklog { get; set; }
    public Issuetype issuetype { get; set; }
    public object timespent { get; set; }
    public Sprint sprint { get; set; }
    public Project project { get; set; }
    public object aggregatetimespent { get; set; }
    public object resolutiondate { get; set; }
    public int workratio { get; set; }
    public Watches watches { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10300 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10301 { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    public object timeoriginalestimate { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Timetracking timetracking { get; set; }
    public List<object> customfield_10401 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10402 { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10006 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10403 { get; set; }
    public object security { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10007 { get; set; }
    public List<object> attachment { get; set; }
    public bool flagged { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10000 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10001 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10002 { get; set; }
    public Customfield10400 customfield_10400 { get; set; }
    public object environment { get; set; }
    public object duedate { get; set; }
    public Comment comment { get; set; }
    public string customfield_10710 { get; set; }
    public Parent parent { get; set; }
}

public class Issue
{
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Issue> issues { get; set; }
}
```

}

I figured I would rather have too many classes and get it to work then I can just weed out what I don't need after (might consider using other properties to generate other graphs, etc). Below is my code that I am trying. I have tried a few other variations but I still get that same unexpected character encountered error.

```
String respStr = response.Content;

        RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(respStr);

        Console.WriteLine(ro.issues[0].key[0]);
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(ro.issues[0].key[0]);` does not work because `key` is a single string. Just remove the index from `key`.

Comment: I went about that however I am still getting that same error. You mentioned that there was a semicolon after issues that throws off the JSON. How would one go about being able to remove that every time, because every time I make a call I get back exactly what I posted.

Comment: You could try to use .Replace(";,"; ",") to remove every semicolon that's at a comma (but be careful because if the JSON contains a `;,` in some string then it will also get changed).

If this is still not working then we might need to check a bigget sample in order to track down the issue.

Comment: So I tried respStr.Replace(";,", ","); and that is still not working